# Import Unity Humaniod into Android App and pass realtime data

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Hi I wanted to ask this question to check if it is possible or not. It would also be great if anyone had some recommended resources to look into.

Is it possible to load a Unity Humanoid model into my android app and then animate the humanoid using data android passes to unity?

I have multiple sensors which you wear on your body, these sensors then pass data to my android app. The plan is to then pass this collected data (realtime) to the humanoid so the humanoid copies all the actions I take when wearing the sensors. Not sure if this helps but this doesnt include jumping or anything like that it is just movement in joints.

Thank you for any help, I already have an app which collects the sensor data so the next step is to somehow import a humanoid to animate this data.